# How to remap a NERDTree shortcut in VIM

Tags: vim, gvim, keymap, key-binding

I use the Dvorak keyboard layout with VIM, and the 't' key is the 'up' motion when editing a regular file.

The problem is that NERDTree remaps 't' to open files in a new tab. How can I undo that mapping and use 't' for the up motion in NERDTree?

Here are the relevant lines from my vimrc file and from the NERDTree plugin.

My .vimrc:

```
no t k
```

NERDTree plugin file:

```
exec "nnoremap <silent> <buffer> ". g:NERDTreeMapOpenInTab ." :call <SID>openInNewTab(0)<cr>"

call s:initVariable("g:NERDTreeMapOpenInTab", "t")

let @h=@h."\" ". g:NERDTreeMapOpenInTab.": open in new tab\n"
```

Answer (score 13):

The documentation for NERDTree shows that you can change the mapping letter for most, if not all of the mappings.  For example, "`:help NERDTree-t`" shows this:

```
Default key: t
Map option: NERDTreeMapOpenInTab
Applies to: files and directories.
```

So in your vimrc you can put something like this to change it from "t" to "\t":

```
let NERDTreeMapOpenInTab='\t'
```

Then NERDTree will stop overriding your preferred functinality of the "t" key in normal mode.

Comment: That worked great !

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps,

```
au vimenter * map t k
```

put this in your vimrc file

Comment: doh! Tried it, and it didn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: I've edited the line. This should work.

Comment: Oh bumcicles....still no dice.

Comment: This is working for me. There could be some other mapping. Better change that "t" in NERDTree to something you dont use..

Comment: The reason this is not working is that NERDTree defines the "t" mapping as a buffer-local mapping on-the-fly every time a NERDTree window is opened, thus overriding any previously defined "t" mapping.  See my answer on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Should avoid doing such a global remap to correct for an undesired mapping in a plugin.  Most provide methods for handling this in a much better way.